# Java XML Reader error

Tags: java, xml, xmlreader, datareader

I get an error when i run the beginning of my XML reader:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("XML Reader");

    try
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse("database.xml");

        //normalize text
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("The root of this doc is "+doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList listOfAddresses = doc.getElementsByTagName("address");
        int totalAddresses = listOfAddresses.getLength();
        System.out.println(totalAddresses+" addresses in "+ doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        //main loop
        for(int i = 0; i<listOfAddresses.getLength(); i++)
        {
            Node items = listOfAddresses.item(i);

            if(items.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
            {
                System.out.println("Address #"+i);

                Element element = (Element)items;

                NodeList nameList = element.getElementsByTagName("name");
                Element nameElement = (Element)nameList.item(0);
                NodeList nameOutput = nameElement.getChildNodes();


                System.out.println("name: "+nameElement);
            }
        }


    }

    catch(SAXParseException err)
    {
        System.out.println("Sax Parse Exception error on line "+err.getLineNumber());
    }

    catch(SAXException e)
    {
        System.out.println("SAX Exception error");
        Exception x = e.getException();
        ((x == null) ? e : x).printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(Throwable t)
    {
        System.out.println("Trowable error");
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

netbeans is giving me the following output:

```
run:
XML Reader
The root of this doc is database
2 addresses in database
java.lang.NullPointerException
Address #0
Trowable error
    at xmlreader.XMLreader.main(XMLreader.java:42)
```

Could someone help me figure this one out?

Comment: and what line is line 42?  Knowing that may help us.

Comment: Always note in the source what line the exception happened.

Answer (score 2):

You're not checking if there IS an element 0.  Essentially, .item() will return null if the index isn't valid, as such there may not be an item with index 0 which returns null and then you try to call getChildNodes() on the null pointer.  Hence your NPE.

You should be iterating over the elements in the node list.

change

```
Element nameElement = (Element)nameList.item(0);
```

to

```
for(int x = 0; x < nameList.getLength(); x++) {
  nameElement = nameList.item(x);
  NodeList nameOutput = nameElement.getChildNodes();
  System.out.println("name: "+nameElement);
}
```